# Keep two Google Maps of different size in sync with zoom levels

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to figure out the ideal zoom for one map if another bigger sized map changes its zoom level. Idea is to keep both maps in sync in terms of viewable area as a smaller map with same zoom will not be viewable the same

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by searching more. You can call fitBounds() function on the map and pass it the bounds you want it to fit.
So `map1.fitBounds(map2.getBounds());`